# How can I use modules in directories outside of the project in react native and expo?

Tags: react-native, babeljs, metro-bundler

I want to use a module external to the project in expo.

The directory structure is below.

```
.
├── back
│   ├── configs
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── src
│   ├── tsconfig.json
│   └── yarn.lock
└── front
    ├── app.json
    ├── babel.config.js
    ├── eas.json
    ├── node_modules
    ├── package.json
    ├── src
    ├── tsconfig.json
    └── yarn.lock
```

I want to use what is under back.
For example, when I want to use back/src/models/Attend, I write the following in my App

```js
import { registerRootComponent } from "expo";
import { StatusBar, View, Text } from "react-native";
import { Attend } from "back/src/models/Attend";

export const App = () => {
  const attend = new Attend("absent");

  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />

      <View>
        <Text>{attend.status}</Text>
      </View>
    </>
  );
};
registerRootComponent(App);
```

And when I simulate it on IOS, I get the following error.

`Unable to resolve "back/src/models/Attend" from "src/App.tsx"`

Attend is definitely present. In fact, code jumps have been made in vscode.

## What I set up

I done `yarn link` with the following command in `front` directory.

`cd ../back; yarn; yarn link; cd ../front; yarn; yarn link back;`

`babel.config.js` is below.

```js
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
    plugins: [
      [
        "module-resolver",
        {
          root: ["./src/"],
          extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".mjs", ".js", ".jsx"],
        },
      ],
    ],
  };
};
```

I have not changed anything in the metro settings.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve this exact same issue by modifying the actual `metro` configuration. Check the Expo [documentation](https://github.com/expo/custom-expo-updates-server).

My configuration (`metro.config.js`) looks like:

```
// Learn more https://docs.expo.io/guides/customizing-metro
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');
const path = require('path')

const config = getDefaultConfig(__dirname)

const extraNodeModules = {
   'Shared': path.resolve(__dirname + '/../shared/')
}

config.resolver = {
    extraNodeModules
}

const watchFolders = [
    path.resolve(__dirname + '/../shared')
];

config.watchFolders = watchFolders

module.exports = config
```

Then on my code, I can do like so:

```
import { WhatEver } from 'Shared'
```